# using Bullet gem for testing with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubygems

I am using rspec or testing API's.
simultaneously I am using bullet gem for identifying N+1 query problem.

Bullet gem works fine in all other environments except test(rspec)

Bullet gem indicates

```
Bullet::Notification::UnoptimizedQueryError: user: karthik
Unused Eager Loading detected
```

and stops the test process to run.

If I remove the corresponding eager loading it works fine, but in development's server log

```
user: karthik
/api/v1/grades
N+1 Query detected
  Grade => [:grade_details]
  Add to your finder: :includes => [:grade_details]
N+1 Query method call stack
```

and also I referred https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet/issues/115
but there also I couldn't get a straight forward answer

Comment: Can you craft a small example that reproduces this ( http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ) ?

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you want Bullet to be executed when runnings specs, or not? Because Bullet will stop running the specs if you have set Bullet.raise.

Comment: @ Robin van Dijk yes I need bullet to be executed while running specs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set `Bullet.raise = false` in test environment then test won't fall. Or disable N+1 queries for defining tests with `Bullet.n_plus_one_query_enable = true`